# Масштабирование спрайта либо GameObject Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать чтобы размер спрайта был равен заданному значению в пикселях?
Если просто делать

```
Sprite.transform.localScale = new Vector3((70), ((70)), 0.001f);
```

То спрайт просто гигански разбухает и вот почему – у него есть внешнее значение localScale, оно изначально = 1,1,1. Но внутри этого значения сам спрайт уже имеет какой то размер, и это точно не 1х1х1 пиксель, а, допустим, 50х50х1 пикселей.  Получается, при данной операции получаем размеры  3500х3500, что разумеется совершенно не нужно.

Вопрос – как получить доступ к внутреннему размеру спрайта, который не в инспекторе изначально 1х1х1, а в проводнике, например 320х160.

Либо, если это не имеет смысла, как просто ровно отмасштабировать спрайт, ровно столько на столько пикселей, сколько мне нужно. 
Пользуюсь Toolkit2d в Unity, так что подойдут решения и оттуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще изменить размер спрайта, который уже лежит в юнити нельзя, на сколько я знаю. В смысле тот был 300px и сделать 400px. То есть изменение размеров в игре и экране никак не является следствием увеличения/уменьшения его физически на носителе.

Если хочется менять размер спрайта, отталкиваясь именно от изначального значения, которое значится в инспекторе, то можно попробовать последовать следующим путем:

Размер спрайта можно взять из поля [rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-rect.html) класса Sprite, который является, в свою очередь полем [sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html) класса [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html).

Т.е. если у объекта с компонентом `SpriteRenderer` в скрипте написать так:

```
Debug.Log(GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.rect.size);
```

то увидим истинные размеры спрайта.

Зная это и зная величину, на которую хотим уменьшить/увеличить спрайт, просто составляем пропорцию, рассчитывая коэффициент и применяем его к `localScale`.

К примеру, хотим уменьшить спрайт по оси `X` на 100px:

```
var originSize = sprite.sprite.rect.size;

var originX = originSize.x;
var destX = originX - 100;
var ratio =  destX / originX;
var scale = transform.localScale;

transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale.x * ratio, scale.y, scale.z);
```

Всё это можно вынести в отдельный метод, как для изменения одной координаты, так и всего спрайта. Это уже на усмотрение. Главное принцип выше.

Answer (score 1):

Размер спрайта в пикселях не имеет смысла, так как спрайт - часть игрового мира. Например, если камера "отъедет назад", абсолютный размер спрайта в пикселях изменится, ведь размер пикселей останется прежним; а вот размер спрайта относительно игрового мира не поменяется. То есть, если нужно, например, увеличить спрайт (марио съел гриб и вырос) - менять нужно относительную величину. Можно ещё [почитать](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/639358/sprite-scale-and-world-scale.html) по теме вопроса, с примером.

Можно так же изменить размер текстуры, на которой основан спрайт:

```
someSprite.texture.Resize(640, 480);
```

Но я не уверен, что это то, что вам нужно.